# here api get House Name

Tags: here-api

I'm currently building an web app which requires to get HOUSE Name (not house number) but api response only returning HouseNumber.

Is there is any attribute need to set to get the house name on reverse Reverse Geocode Resource.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a house *name* that you are interested in.  Just to help clarify if you are interested in landmarks, points of interest, business names, or something different?

Comment: i.e. Kemp House, Gold Club Media Ltd Kemp House, 152-160, City Road, Central, London, EC1V 2NX

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we don't have any house names. Famous buildings(eg: film star houses), apartments which are considered POI are listed under category: building and have title field which is the name of the building. See an example below (use your app id and code):

```
https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?at=19.05743%2C72.83659&q=Bella+Vista+Apartments&Geolocation=geo%3A19.057769%2C72.836137&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.5&app_id=xxxxx&app_code=xxxxx
```